# undefined method because of self.new?

Tags: ruby

```
 class Per
    def prkey(somevar)
      @card = somevar
    end

    def self.some_class
      puts self
    end

    def self.new
     @card = 'ss'
    end
   end

Per.some_class
Per.new.prkey('hi')
```

**I got the error  :**

> undefined method `prkey' for "ss":String (NoMethodError)

because of the self.new ? After I comment out self.new, there is no error. That is weird.

Comment: why are you doing `self.new` the method should be a `def initialize` method

Comment: In ruby, you don't normally override `self.new`. I never had to do that.

Answer (score 4):

`.new` is Ruby's built in function for initializing new instances of a class, by defining your own `.new` you are hijacking the behaviour and therefore new instances aren't being instantiated.

If you want something to happen every time an instance of a class is instantiated put it in the `initialize` method.

Replace your `self.new` method with:

```
def initialize
    @card = "ss"
end
```

Comment: Awesome! Consider accepting this (or one of the other) answer.

Comment: My reputation is 14. It is not enough to vote the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You overrode the `new` method. So now when you call `Per.new`, it will return `ss` string, rather than an instance of class `Per`.

Then you are calling `prkey` method on an instance of `String` class, which is not defined.

As it was recommended in the comment to your question, you need to use `def initialize` instead of `def self.new`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep doing self.new implementation, you can call super to return the object you need like this:

```
class Per
    def prkey(somevar)
        @card = somevar
    end

    def self.some_class
        puts self
    end

    def self.new
        @card = 'ss'
        super
    end
end

Per.some_class
Per.new.prkey('hi')
```

However like people have already answered, it is better to implement the initialize method:

```
class Per
    attr_accessor :card # getter and setter for card    

    def initialize(card)
        @card = card
    end
end

per = Per.new("hi")
puts per.card # hi
per.card = "hello"
puts per.card # hello
```

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful.